# Excel VBA optimize

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have below Excel VBA code in many places. It need to optimize to improve running speed. I do appreciate your help.

Someone within a loop:

```
For x = A_OFFSET_MARKETVALUE To A_OFFSET_CURRENT
    Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next x
```

For example: the above code copy `Cells(11,13).Formula "=SUM(M12:M13)"` to `Cells(11,14).Formula`, After copy and `xlPasteFormulas`  `Cells(11,14).Formula` becomes `"=SUM(N12:N13)` does anybody know why? But the result is expected. So if I use below code to optimized it

```
Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Formula = Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Formula
```

The `Cells(11,14).Formula` always is `"=SUM(M12:M13)"`. I do not know why? How should I optimized it and also get `Cells(11,14).Formula` value `"=SUM(N12:N13)"`

Someone is not in a loop:

```
Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_MARKETVALUE).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

The whole code is below for reference. There are many places need to be optimized. Unfortunately, I am very new to VBA,and my boss required it to be done in a very short time. So anybody can help me will be greate appreciated.
Many many thanks.

Comment: `Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Formula = Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Formula`

Comment: Do not use `.Select` or `.Activate` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: I had tried Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Formula = Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Formula but the result calculate value is not correct.

Comment: If you show more of your code we can help more.  At least show how you set the variables

Comment: Hi Scott, Please see updated post with more code. many thanks!

Comment: Hi Scott, the original code copy Cells(11,13).Formula "=SUM(M12:M13)" to Cells(11,14).Formula, Cells(11,14).Formula becomes to "=SUM(N12:N13), Do you know Why?

Comment: @DeepinDevelopment That is because Excel adjusts formulas automatically (by default). You can stop that by using `$` like `=SUM($M12:$M13)` to fix the column or `=SUM($M$12:$M$13)` to fix column and row.

Comment: I refer to you the **most active** [tag:VBA]-related question on S.O. :  "[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/8112776)" 